# CRUD'ing Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract - a smart move?

Tags: php, oop, crud

in my code i've created an Object that returns an active link to the Database.
this object is being inherited by a CRUD object i've created that would have create/retrieve/update/delete functions as well as all Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract functionality.
next in the chain would be a table specific manager object such as example user table or links table

is CRUDing Zend_DB object is a smart move does what i've described here sounds like a logically design ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need better mvc architecture then separate models into business logic layer and DAO layer.

Suppose you have User object to hold users business logic methods like getAccountInfo, resetPassword. Use userDAO to deal all database related methods like insertUser, updateUser.